# How to add HTTP status code with error message in spring

Tags: spring-data-jpa, http-status-code-405

I created one spring data jpa Application. In this application my method request is GET. but if I am trying to access that method Request url as post request. In this situation I want to know how to add HTTP status code 405(Method Not Allowed) with my custom error message.

Here is my code snippet

DepartmentModel

```
package com.demo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class DepartmentModel implements Serializable {  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @Id         
    public  Integer ndeptid;    
    public String sdeptname ;
    public  Integer ninstid  ;
    public Boolean bislocked;
    public String sclientdeptid;
    public Integer nsurveymethodid;
    public Boolean bisjointuse;
    public Integer ntempdeptid;
    public  Boolean balternatejointusepercentage;
    public Integer ndivid;
    //getter and setter
```

DepartmentRepository

```
@Repository
public interface DepaertmentRepository extends JpaRepository<DepartmentModel, Integer>
{
    @Query("select new map(dep.sdeptname as sdeptname)"
            + " from DepartmentModel as dep where dep.ninstid=60")  
    Set<DepartmentModel> findBySDepName();
    }
```

DepartmentService

```
@Service
    public class DepartmentService
    {   
        @Autowired
        DepaertmentRepository depRepo;

        public   Set<DepartmentModel> findDepName()
        {
            return depRepo.findBySDepName();

        }   
    }
```

DepartmentController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/SpaceStudy/SpaceAdmin")
public class DepartmentController {

    @Autowired
    DepartmentService depService;


    @CrossOrigin(origins="*")
    @GetMapping("AccountMaintenance/LoadDepartment")
    //@ResponseStatus( value = HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED) 
    public  Set<DepartmentModel> findDepName() {

            return depService.findDepName();
    }
}
```

can any one help me how to add HTTP status code (405) with proper message when i am accessing GET request as post

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method `handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported` of `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and implement your own error message object. For example:

```java
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest req) {

    headers.setAllow(ex.getSupportedHttpMethods());
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = ErrorMessage.of(
            status.value(), 
            "You cannot make this request - the method is not allowed!", 
            ex.getMessage(), 
            ((ServletWebRequest) req).getRequest().getServletPath() 
    );
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, headers, status);
}

@Value(staticConstructor = "of")
private static class ErrorMessage {
    private Instant timestamp = Instant.now();
    private Integer status;
    private String error;
    private String message;
    private String path;
}
```

See my full [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/single-file-app) for more info.

You can override not only this method of `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` but all the remaining to get custom handling of other exceptions.

Note: you can use another approach to handle exceptions (or use both) - implement an [exception handler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

**UPDATE**

It's necessary to add `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to the class that extended `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Using this code I can handle exception. if I am not wrong  before handling exception we need to throw that exception from service.how to throw that exception

Comment: @R.Shinde You don't need to throw he exception - Spring do it itself. Just create a simple controller with one method (for example GET "/people") and request GET "/users" instead. You will see the error message with corresponding exception in it...

Comment: i tryied like this but its giving me default error message 404 (not found)

Comment: i am asking  about method not supported(trying to access  post instead of get). i think you are saying about wrong URL

Comment: @R.Shinde Try to request 'POST /people' instead of GET (it's difficult to remember all variants ) ). See remaining methods of [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html) - you can override them all.

Comment: yes,i tried to access method as post through  postman but its not giving any response. nothing is printing

Comment: @R.Shinde I found the reason - it's necessary to add `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to the class that extended `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. I updated my demo and [added](https://github.com/Cepr0/single-file-app/blob/502584f715d9fd20bb229634bce483e2f54c5778/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/singlefileapp/Application.java#L148) overridden method `handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported`.